# What free scientific measures of Big 5 personality are available?

Tags: measurement, personality

I'm aware of a few freely available scientific measures of Big 5 personality.

- [IPIP](http://ipip.ori.org/):
- [Ten Item Personality Inventory (TIPI)](http://homepage.psy.utexas.edu/homepage/faculty/gosling/tipi%20site/tipi.htm)

#### Questions:

- What other free scientific Big 5 personality tests are available?
- In particular, I'd be interested in any free measures of the Big 5 that are framed so that introversion, neuroticism, disagreeableness, etc. are slightly more positive.

Specifically, all items need to be available and it needs to be published in the scientific literature with reasonable reliability and validity data.

Answer (score 5):

#### IPIP

It should be noted that the [IPIP has a range of multi-construct versions](http://ipip.ori.org/newMultipleconstructs.htm) that are designed to align with some existing measures.

- [IPIP mapped to NEO-PI-R](http://ipip.ori.org/newNEODomainsKey.htm)

#### The Big Five Inventory (BFI)

The BFI is available [here in the Appendix](http://pages.uoregon.edu/sanjay/pubs/bigfive.pdf) of John and Srivastava (1999). Sanjay Srivastava has a [page discussing the measure here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/sanjay/bigfive.html). (Note the page also directed  me to other options I mention below). It is not public domain but it appears to be free for research.

It is a 44 item measure of the Big 5. Each item involves short sentences.

#### Big 5 Aspects Scale

As [Sanjay Srivastava](http://pages.uoregon.edu/sanjay/bigfive.html#other) writes:

> Colin DeYoung and colleagues have published a 100-item measure, called
>   the [Big Five Aspect Scales (BFAS)](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~cdeyoung/Research.htm), which scores not only the Big Five
>   factors, but also two "aspects" of each. The BFAS is in the public
>   domain as well.

#### 100 Unipolar Markers

[Sanjay Srivastava](http://pages.uoregon.edu/sanjay/bigfive.html#other) notes that there is "Lew Goldberg's set of 100
 trait-descriptive adjectives" (Goldberg, 1992).

#### Big 5 Mini Markers

> Gerard Saucier reduced [Goldberg's] set to [40 Big Five mini-markers](http://pages.uoregon.edu/gsaucier/gsau41.htm)
>   that have excellent reliability and validity (Saucier, 1994). 
>   More recently, Saucier has developed new trait
>   marker sets that maximize the orthogonality of the factors (Saucier, 2002). Saucier's mini-markers are in the
>   public domain.

#### HEXACO Personality Inventory-Revised

While the [HEXACO](http://hexaco.org/) is actually based on a six factor model of personality, it does share similarities to the Big 5. Specifically, five of the six dimensions map on to the Big 5, and HEXACO adds honesty-humility.
[60 and 100 item versions](http://hexaco.org/downloading.html) of the test are available on the website (and 200 item version is available by request).

#### References

- Goldberg, L. R. (1992). The development of markers for the Big-Five factor structure. Psychological assessment, 4(1), 26. [PDF](http://www.psych.utoronto.ca/users/peterson/Psy2302011/14Goldberg.pdf)
- John, O. P., & Srivastava, S. (1999). The Big Five trait taxonomy: History, measurement, and theoretical perspectives. Handbook of personality: Theory and research, 2, 102-138. [PDF](http://pages.uoregon.edu/sanjay/pubs/bigfive.pdf)
- Saucier, G. (1994). Mini-markers: A brief version of Goldberg's unipolar Big-Five markers. Journal of personality assessment, 63(3), 506-516. [PDF](http://pages.uoregon.edu/prsnlty/SAUCIER/Saucier.Minimarkers.Full.pdf)
- Saucier,G. (2002).  Orthogonal markers for orthogonal factors: The case of the Big Five.  Journal of Research in Personality,  36(1), 1-31. [PDF](http://darkwing.uoregon.edu/~prsnlty/SAUCIER/Saucier.Ortho-40.FullPaper.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

The **BFI-10** is another short version, a pared-down-to-ten-items variant of the Big Five Inventory...

Rammstedt, B., & John, O. P. (2007). Measuring personality in one minute or less: A 10-item short version of the Big Five Inventory in English and German. *Journal of Research in Personality, 41*(1), 203–212. Available online, URL: http://www.westmont.edu/_academics/departments/psychology/documents/Rammstedt_and_John.pdf.