# Which are the most accredited tests for measuring personality traits?

Tags: personality, test

I'm lacking of an academic background. I thought there were only 4 or 16 personality traits. But a fast search on google is showing a huge number: according to this [link](http://ideonomy.mit.edu/essays/traits.html) they should be 638.

Is this information correct?

Which are the most accredited tests for measuring personality traits?

Comment: I think this is an OK question! I even had a similar exam question as a student for my personality psychology course: "Why big 5 instead of big 3 or small 16?" (i.e. Costa&McCrae vs. Eysenck vs. Spearman).

Comment: @Ana: thanks, if you like it I would appreciate a +1!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How many personality factors are there?**
The history of personality testing can be summarised in terms of an initial period where there was a vast number of personality traits. In response to this, there have been various attempts to synthesise these traits into a smaller number of underlying factors. There is a huge literature on this process (e.g., Digman, 1990; McCrae & John, 1992).

There are a lot of researchers who have proposed variations on the five factor model (commonly labeled OCEAN: openness, conscientiousness, extraversion agreeableness, and neuroticism). That said, you will find a range of other factorial models (e.g., Eysenk's three factor model; the [HEXACO](http://hexaco.org/) six factor model).

There has also been subsequent challenges to the resulting dominance of factorial models.
For example, see the research of Sampo Paunonen (e.g., Paunonen & Ashton, 2001) which suggests that we may have gone too far in embracing the factorial models of personality.

Related to this debate, there are a range of hiearchical theories of personality where facets are nested within factors. So you can either get a very general representation of personality with say 5 factors, and a more detailed representation with say 30 facets.

**What are valid measures of these factors?**
There are a large number of well validated personality tests.
Tests are typically built around particular representations of personality.
There are a range of [free measures of the Big 5 listed here](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/what-free-scientific-measures-of-big-5-personality-are-available) with some discussion around validity.

The NEO is one of the most well-known and used commercial measures of the Big 5. That said, there are a wide range of well validated commercial personality tests available.

#### References

- Digman, J. M. (1990). Personality structure: Emergence of the five-factor model. Annual review of psychology, 41(1), 417-440.
- McCrae, R. R., & John, O. P. (1992). An introduction to the five‐factor model and its applications. Journal of personality, 60(2), 175-215.
- Paunonen, S. V., & Ashton, M. C. (2001). Big five factors and facets and the prediction of behavior. Journal of personality and social psychology, 81(3), 524.

Comment: Is it "bad" to open a question asking how NEO relates to MBTI?

Comment: Have you seen this answer? http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/1546/is-there-any-personality-theory-that-uses-scientific-methodology-instead-of-subj